# Hubot multiple messages

Tags: coffeescript, slack, hubot

I have the following script:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->

  robot.respond /petsit/i, (res) ->

    user_name = res.envelope.user.name
    res.reply "Starting new petsitting under: @" + user_name + "\n"
    res.send "What is the dog's name? Reply with 'dog `INSERT_DOG_NAME`'"

    robot.respond /dog (.*)/i, (msg) ->
      dog_name = msg.match[1]

      user_dog_name = "" + user_name + dog_name

      if robot.brain.get(user_dog_name)
        msg.send "Petsitting is already in progress for @" + user_name + " Dog: " + dog_name
      else
        robot.brain.set(user_app_name, true)
        msg.send "#{dog_name} " + robot.brain.get(user_app_name)
```

I'm confused why I'm getting multiple messages when I call petsit multiple times?

For example:

```
@hubot petsit
@hubot dog lucky

@hubot petsit
@hubot dog kenny ---> This will give me multiple messages.
```

My thought is that this is async and the 2nd message is being run by the 1st dialouges/conversation? How do i fix this so that the 1st conversation does not interfere with following conversations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting multiple messages because the `robot.respond /dog (.*)/i` listener is attached every time the `robot.respond /petsit/i` is called.  That is the first time you send **petsit** the `/dog (.*)/i` listener is attached for the first time.  When you send **dog ...** only one response will be triggered.  Every subsequent time you send **petsit** the second listener will bind itself on the same **robot** instance, thus sending you multiple responses.

By default there is no native support from Hubot for managing conversations.  Instead you should have a look at a 3rd party module like [hubot-conversation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hubot-conversation)
that adds this type of functionality or implement your own logic.